# How to solve an equation where $x$ is exponent of $2$ different bases?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I've got an equation where variable I'm looking for is an exponent of $2$ different bases:

$$a^x+b^x=c$$

If I know $a, b$ and $c$, how can I calculate $x$?

I was thinking of taking logarithm of both sides to somehow use the rule that $\log(a^x) = x\cdot\log(a)$, but this doesn't help me much as I have the logarithm of sum on the left side:

$$\log(a^x+b^x)=\log(c)$$

Now I'm a bit stuck at this point, any hints as to how to approach this?

Comment: Do you have a specific example in mind? To my knowledge, examples like these often occur when $a$ and $b$ are powers of the same number. For example, $a=9$ and $b=27$.

Comment: There's probably no closed-form solution, but it should be easy to solve numerically, eg using Newton's method.

Comment: in my example a and b are completely unrelated - I'm trying to calculate how much time I need to save until I can pay off my mortgage completely. However I transform these equations (principal left on one side, built capital on the other one) I always end up with some terms where N (number of months I'm looking for) is a power of both (1+r) and (1+m) where r is return of savings (say 4%) and m is interest on mortgage (2.8%)

I wanted to find some easy to compute formula but I guess I'll end up calculating this in a loop

Comment: Have you tried dividing throughout by $a^x$ i remember a somewhat similar question being done like that

Comment: Here is a short [Sage script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVTkEKgzAQvPuKOWatWhR6kQb6EmGjsUhDWlIPeX53lUo7l11mhpm5LXH1ice1mPyM2bBtm7aCk9NVGO2F-gKCwBWCg0WIhqnS42hTspCmQ6nUSDjDBMZJzERNNLtnfiYsWCISx7s33TdVwVnqNIQH_YZ8KK8k44yQnCXQZTqUSTtH1KrUquy15WYMrvz1CmUxHVMUywx2bzMRrmh93XY9XPL8KP5bh612yPQB0nZGyg==&lang=sage) using Newton's method which converges fairly quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that $1\lt a \lt b.$ Thus, $r:={\log b\over\log a}\gt 1.$
Let $t=a^x.$ Thus, $t^r=b^x.$ Therefore, $a^x+b^x=c$ becomes
$t+t^r=c\tag 1$
We assume that $x$ is positive so that $t\gt 1$ and $c\gt 2.$ The derivative of $f(t),$ the left side of (1),  is positive for $t>1.$ Since $f(1)\lt c,$ the solution of (1) exists and is unique. Thus, we know $a^x,$ and can calculate $x.$ (For example if $a=2$ and $b=3,$ then $r$ is approximately 1.58496250072 )

Comment: Thank you, this looks almost like solution, but how do I solve $t + t^r = c$ for $r$ that's not an integer? Are there solutions other than numerical?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the example $2^2+3^2=13,$ I typed
"solve t+t^(1.585)=13" in Google which sent me to
[www.mathway.com](http://www.mathway.com) which gave me the answer  t≈3.99989753
Then I changed  13 to 97 on Mathway and got t≈15.99906678
Since a=2, you now know the value of $x$ that I used.